# USB 2-1 Over-Current message

Tags: boot, usb

I recently upgraded my system from 16.04 to 17.04 and I am now constantly receiving the message (looping in ctrl+alt=F1 and in dmesg:

```
[  473.112642] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
[  473.328636] usb 2-1-port5: over-current condition
[  473.544638] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
[  473.760677] usb 2-1-port5: over-current condition
[  475.488663] usb 2-1-port5: over-current condition
[  475.704640] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
```

I've looked around and found that it is usually an empty warning and all my USB ports are working and intact.

I have tried editing /etc/default/grub with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash,ehci_hcd.ignore_oc=1" but the warning still shows up.

I've also tried looking at the other topics similar to mine and haven't found a solid solution/ set of instructions on inserting the ignore_oc command.

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux in general so if you need anything from me let me know!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Okay, so i've been looking through some log files and found the message starts after it has detected my keyboard. I've posted the output below but still have no idea how to go about resolving this.

```
    Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    1.812826] hid-generic 0003:2516:0015.0004: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [CM Storm Quickfire Pro Ultimate 6 key] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    1.828474] input: CM Storm Quickfire Pro Ultimate 6 key as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:2516:0015.0005/input/input5
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    1.884905] hid-generic 0003:2516:0015.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [CM Storm Quickfire Pro Ultimate 6 key] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input1
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    1.944741] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    2.376766] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    2.656901] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    3.024758] usb 2-1-port5: over-current condition
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    3.456758] usb 2-1-port5: over-current condition
Apr 24 09:18:09 Joe-PC kernel: [    3.672760] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've got an external powered USB hub, and the AC power adapter has come unplugged, or is defective? What is plugged into ports 5 and 6? Does the error message go away if you unplug those devices? How about if you plug those same devices directly into a port on the computer?

Comment: Hi, no I don't have a USB hub plugged into the computer. The only USB devices are keyboard and mouse. If I unplug them the message still loops

Comment: In your BIOS, are there any USB settings... like "legacy", or "compatible", or "USB3", etc?

Comment: I have legacy USB support options and they are enabled

Comment: ps: is this just a typo? GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash,ehci_hcd.ignore_oc=1" should be GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ehci_hcd.ignore_oc=1", and then a `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: What are the other USB choices besides legacy?

Comment: No that's not a typo, just wasn't sure how to insert it to be honest! And it's just an option to enable or disable legacy support. Thank you so far but I have work in the morning so will reply to any more comments/ suggestions tomorrow! Thanks again

Comment: Remove your ehci string, update-grub, and select something different than legacy in your BIOS, and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, I've tried what you suggested and turning off legacy support didn't change anything except making my keyboard unavailable on the grub screen. I can't try removing the ignore_oc command as now my Ubuntu install won't boot. Not sure if it's related or not though

Comment: Okay, i've ended up doing a clean install of 17.04 to get my Ubuntu to boot. The over-current message is still appearing so that's still a thing!

Comment: I've editted my question with some more information

Comment: But you said that you got the error messages even when the keyboard was unplugged, yes? I don't think that we ever checked that you have the latest BIOS for your model computer, did we? You should do that asap.

Comment: Yes that's right. I'll double check my BIOS version and update it if needed and get back to you

Comment: Okay BIOS is now up to date and the message is still appearing :(

Comment: Good job on updating your BIOS. You might google "the make/model of your computer, and usb" and see if you get any hits. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas then.

Comment: It's a PC I built myself so I wouldn't be able to do that. I'll just have to live with it. Thanks for all your suggestions :)

Comment: Yes, but, for example, if you used an ASUS motherboard, you could still Google "asus usb" and see if you caught any hits. It may be a common problem with your motherboard.

Comment: Doh! Of course, sorry I'm not normally this dumb. It's been a long day

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware problem caused by shorting in the USB electrical system. (please repair those ports or try another keyboard/mouse before you cause a fire)

Answer (score 4):

Over current condition is related to abnormal current flow higher than expected. This is a hardware problem in your USB port (or other component related to USB). In most of the cases, this is caused by dust/humidity (Remember that most of dust is, in general, dead skin and it is a very good humidity holder).

You shouldn't simply ignore this condition. There is an electrical issue in your motherboard. If the ports are attached by cable, you can pull it out. Otherwise, if the ports are soldered in the MB, it will be more difficult to sane.

My first attempt to resolve is do a very very detailed clean on the motherboard. Works in the majority of the cases.

Some rare cases, the ports need to be replaced. In only one, I solved by replacing a capacitor.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be a typo, you need to use spaces as delimiter of multiple boot options (as in "quiet splash"). So instead of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash,ehci_hcd.ignore_oc=1"` try

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ehci_hcd.ignore_oc=1"
```

You can check whether it worked by running

```
cat /sys/module/ehci_hcd/parameters/ignore_oc
```

after the reboot. If it yields "Y", the boot parameter was set; if it yields "N" something went wrong, check spelling (musst be all lower case) and whether you indeed ran

```
sudo update-grub
```

after setting the option and before the restart.