# Over-current condition appears in dmesg when kenel option ehci_hcd.ignore_oc=1

Tags: usb, kernel

I've read next question:
[USB 2-1 Over-Current message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908165/usb-2-1-over-current-message)

Did next thing:

```
slava@slava-Aspire-5742G:~$ cat /sys/module/ehci_hcd/parameters/ignore_oc
Y

slava@slava-Aspire-5742G:~$ dmesg
...
[ 2634.156010] usb 2-1-port5: over-current condition
[ 2634.372006] usb 2-1-port6: over-current condition
[ 2634.592053] usb 2-1-port2: over-current condition
```

Is that a hacker joke or how to fix it?

Comment: Do you really have problems with USB hardware ports? Why do you apply the mentioned option? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Pots are working. I need zero such messages in tty because sometimes i use it. Hacker option? Or ignore_oc option? if second - the referenced link talks about that.